# How to calculate the R Squared given limited information?

Tags: regression, r-squared

I am attempting to solve the following problem from my Statistics class:

- WALC=β_0 + β_1 TOTEXP + β_2 AGE + β_3 EDUC + β_4 SIZE + e.
- Suppose RSS=2032.73 and SD(WALC)=12.4537. N = 45. What is R Squared?

I feel like there is very limited information given, but somehow the Professor said we could calculate R Squared.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve?

I know that the general formula for R Squared = 1 - RSS / TSS. However, I am not sure how to find TSS from just SD(WALC).

Your feedback would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: How does the standard deviation relate to the variance? How does the variance relate to the total sum of squares?

Comment: Thanks Monica! If I square the sd(WALC) then I get the variance of Y. Is the variance of Y the ESS ?

Comment: Victor, look up the definition of variance and see how it relates to the sum of squares